# Hide program title from ubuntu unity menubar

Tags: 14.04, unity, customization, launcher

Is it possible to hide the application title from the menubar?

Comment: What is exactly the reason for not showing the application name?

Comment: It distracts me, I can see which program is active.

Comment: I see. It is currently not possible to prevent displaying the name in the launcher. I can imagine it would be(-come) a setting option in "Appearance" as far as it concerns the Launcher (also updated the answer).

Answer (score 2):

Simply: No
The name in both the Unity Launcher and Dash is determined by the line in the corresponding `.desktop` file, e.g.:

```
Name=Bluefish Editor
```

[image]

This line is in the categorie: "Required" as you can read [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html) , which means you cannot have a "nameless" `.desktop` file which is considered to be a correct one.

Unity also simply does not allow a "nameless" representation. In fact, looking up an application in *Dash* is *based on* the presence of its name. A "nameless" application would therefore clash with the concept of Dash.

I can imagine it would be(-come) a setting option in "Appearance" as far as it concerns the Launcher.

Comment: ` you cannot have a "nameless" .desktop file which is considered to be a correct one.` I think you mean "nameless" .desktop file is incorrect one

Comment: @Serg I am not sure I understand what you mean :)  I mean to say: "You cannot have a nameless `.desktop` file, which is (still) considered to be a correct one" .

Comment: I thought you mistyped on that line or something. I see now what you meant.